# Как считать элементы с textEdit и добавить их в матрицу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку ("Рассчитать"), считывались числа с моих `textEdit_1` - `textEdit_20` и записывались в матрицу. Но не знаю, как задать диапазон в `textEdit_1` - `textEdit_20`.

Вот, что у меня есть:

```
M = [[0 for j in range(5)] for i in range(4)]
  for i in range(4):
     for j in range(5):
        M[i][j] = int(self.textEdit_1.toPlainText())
```

Планируется, что для `M[0][0]` значение будет браться с `textEdit_1` (сейчас там `1`), `для M[0][1]` с `textEdit_2` (там стоит `2`) и т.д.

Как это реализовать?

---

**UPD:** Пытался изменить так, но теперь все элементы матрицы имеют значение `None`

```
  n = 1
  for i in range(4):
     for j in range(5):
        M[i][j] = exec('int(self.textEdit_{}.toPlainText())'.format(n))
        n += 1
```

---

**UPD2:** Ага, оказывается `exec()` возвращает `None` и эту инструкцию категорически нельзя присваивать. Нужно воспользоваться `eval()`:

```
  n = 1
  for i in range(4):
     for j in range(5):
        M[i][j] = eval('int(self.textEdit_{}.toPlainText())'.format(n))
        n += 1
```

---

[image]

Comment: Содавай textEdit'ы программно, занеси их в массив и обращайся к каждому по нормальному имени... а форму компануй layout'ами... QGridLayout как раз для таких целей подойдёт...

Comment: @february я добавил в свой ответ пример с правильным использованием метода `exec()`. Пробуйте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При программном создании формы с виджетами, лучше в контейнере хранить список виджетов и через него с ним работать, пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.row_count = 4
        self.column_count = 5

        self.button_calc = QPushButton('CALCULATE!')
        self.button_calc.clicked.connect(self._on_calculate)

        layout_grid_input = QGridLayout()
        self.matrix_input = []
        for i in range(self.row_count):
            self.matrix_input.append([])

            for j in range(self.column_count):
                cell = QLineEdit(str(i * j))
                cell.setFixedSize(20, 20)

                self.matrix_input[i].append(cell)
                layout_grid_input.addWidget(cell, i, j)

        layout_grid_result = QGridLayout()
        self.matrix_result = []
        for i in range(self.row_count):
            self.matrix_result.append([])

            for j in range(self.column_count):
                cell = QLabel()
                cell.setFrameStyle(QLabel.Box)
                cell.setFixedSize(20, 20)

                self.matrix_result[i].append(cell)
                layout_grid_result.addWidget(cell, i, j)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Input:'))
        layout.addLayout(layout_grid_input)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Result:'))
        layout.addLayout(layout_grid_result)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_calc)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def _on_calculate(self):
        for i in range(self.row_count):
            for j in range(self.column_count):
                value = int(self.matrix_input[i][j].text())
                value *= 2

                self.matrix_result[i][j].setText(str(value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если же у вас уже есть форма с виджетами и нужно эти виджеты получить, то лучше по `objectName`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.row_count = 4
        self.column_count = 5

        ...

        # Пример создания виджетов с objectName
        self.initUI()

        layout_grid_input = QGridLayout()
        self.matrix_input = []
        for i in range(self.row_count):
            self.matrix_input.append([])

            for j in range(self.column_count):
                # Найдем наш виджет по его objectName
                cell = self.findChild(QWidget, "cell_{}x{}".format(i, j))
                self.matrix_input[i].append(cell)
                layout_grid_input.addWidget(cell, i, j)

        ...

    def initUI(self):
        for i in range(self.row_count):
            for j in range(self.column_count):
                line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
                line_edit.setText(str(i * j))
                line_edit.setFixedSize(20, 20)
                line_edit.setObjectName('cell_{}x{}'.format(i, j))

    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В дизайнере, у каждого виджета есть свойство `objectName`, и вы ему можете установить значение, и по нему найти виджет.

Например, установить `objectName` в соответствии с положением виджета на сетке, пример:

```
cell_0x0 cell_0x1 cell_0x2 cell_0x3 cell_0x4 
cell_1x0 cell_1x1 cell_1x2 cell_1x3 cell_1x4 
cell_2x0 cell_2x1 cell_2x2 cell_2x3 cell_2x4 
cell_3x0 cell_3x1 cell_3x2 cell_3x3 cell_3x4
```

Answer (score 4):

Если вы поместите значения textEdit_1 - textEdit_20 в список listTextEdit. 
Например:
`listTextEdit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`

тогда это может выглядеть так:

```
M = [[0 for j in range(5)] for i in range(4)]
n = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        M[i][j] = listTextEdit[i+j+n]
    n += 4
```

Результат: M

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
```

Очень сомневаюсь в необходимости использования метода `exec()` в данном случае.
Но если вы хотите так попробовать, тогда это может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        for n in range(1, 21):
            exec('self.textEdit_{0} = QTextEdit("{0}")'.format(n))

        M = [[0 for j in range(5)] for i in range(4)]

        n = 1
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(5):
                exec('M[i][j] =self.textEdit_{0}.toPlainText()'.format(n))
                n += 1   

        for i in range(4):
            print(M[i])    
            #label = QLabel("{}".format(i), self)
            line = ", ".join([ str(j) for j in M[i]])
            label = QLabel(line, self)
            label.move(20, i*10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем писать `super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)`, если можно `super().__init__(parent)`? :)

Comment: Qgil9red я же не волшебник, я только учусь :)